# sort by aggregate values of a list of dictionaries in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I've list of directories and list with student marks and subjects. I would like to sort the student record based on total and replace the subjects which are not found for a student with 0.

```
student_data=[{u'sub_1': 51, u'sub_2': 72, u'sub_4': 62, 'user': u'student_1'}, {u'subj_1': 45, u'subj_2': 56, u'subj_6': 71, 'user': u'student_2'}, {u'sub_1': 81, u'sub_3': 67, u'sub_5': 72, 'user': u'student_3'}]
subjects=['sub_1','sub_2','sub_3','sub_4','sub_5','sub_6']
```

**Expected output:**

```
Student     sub_1  sub_2  sub_3  sub_4  sub_5  sub_6
student_3   81     0      67     0      72     0
student_1   51     72     0      62     0      0
student_2   45     56     0      0      0      71
```

The logic that I've used in the following code is not great. My final output would be like sort the student records based on total.

sample code:

```
>>> for student in student_data:
...     sys.stdout.write('\n' + '{:20s}'.format(student['user']))
...     del student['user']
...     for k, v in student.items():
...         for i in subjects:
...             if i == k:
...                 sys.stdout.write('{:5s}'.format(str(v)))
...             else:
...                 sys.stdout.write('{:5s}'.format(str("0")))
... 

student_1           0    72   0    0    0    0    51   0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    62   0    0    
student_2           0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    
student_3           0    72   0    0    0    0    0    0    67   0    0    0    81   0    0    0    0    0    >>>
```

Comment: why is `subjects` not made of unicode strings? why does `student_2` have `subj_N` instead of `sub_N`? Why are you using `sys.stdout.write` instead of `print` with a trailing `,` to prevent the newline, or `from __future__ import print_function` with `print(..., end='')`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `get` with a default value to get the grade for each subject or `0` if that subject is not present. Then just get the `sum` of those and use that as the `key` for sorting, in `reverse` order.

Also, you can simplify the body of the loop, again using `get` with default combined with `str.join` instead of that inner double `for` loop.

```
for student in sorted(student_data, 
                      key=lambda d: sum(d.get(subj, 0) for subj in subjects), 
                      reverse=True):
    scores = "".join(("{:3}".format(student.get(subj, 0)) for subj in subjects))
    print("{:10s} {}".format(student["user"], scores))
```

Output:

```
student_3   81  0 67  0 72  0
student_1   51 72  0 62  0  0
student_2    0  0  0  0  0  0
```